# Cat not writing special variables in file

Tags: bash, shell, cat

I am using cat to write into file with script shell.

```
 cat <<EOF >/home/test.txt
 set $value1 $value2;
 EOF
```

My file containts just this string "set ;" but i need to find "set $value1 $value2;". I guess cat thinks "$value1" is a shell variable but it is just a string that i need to write into a file.

Comment: Are you really writing to `/home/test.txt`? Normally the `/home` directory only contains users' home directories, not files -- and non-root users usually don't have permission to write to it anyway.

Comment: By the way, `cat` does not see variables.  All that happens is that the shell writes the data to a temporary file, and `cat` reads that.  The magic is done (or not) by the shell, `cat` is as dumb as a bag of rocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use quotes around EOF:

```
cat <<"EOF" >/home/test.txt
set $value1 $value2;
EOF
```

From the **Here Documents** section in `man bash`:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>    <<[-]word
>            here-document
>    delimiter
> ```
>
> If any characters  in  word  are  quoted,  the delimiter  is  the 
>   result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here- document
>   are not expanded.  If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document
>   are  subjected  to  parameter  expansion,  command substitution, and
>   arithmetic expansion.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `<<'EOF'` rather than `<<"EOF"`. They're equivalent, but in a quoted string double quotes permit expansion and single quotes don't.